# "Everything you bought I had already bought before."

Tags: fronting

An example of topicalization ( = fronting) from [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization):

> - **(1a)** *I won't eat that pizza*. — without fronting
> - **(1b)** *That pizza, I won't eat*. — with fronting

My own example:
John and Tom are going hiking.
They need to buy together a number of specific things for it.
John bought all these things but Tom didn't know about it and bought them too.
John is saying to Tom:

> - **(2a)** *I had already bought before everything you bought*. — without fronting
> - **(2b)** *Everything you bought I had already bought before*. — with fronting

It seems to me (2a) is odd and, therefore, (2b) is the only way to formulate the thought.

To find out whether my context is appropriate for fronting or not, tell me please:
Is (2a) natural?
Is (2b) natural?
If (2b) is not natural, then why not?
If (2b) is not natural, how to rephrase it?

Comment: In 2a, the tense had bought = already = before, it's too redundant in my view. 
If you remove one, and change to "everything **that** you bought", the sentence will be more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that neither (2a) nor (2b) is fully natural, and that the expression "*bought before*" is unusual, and sounds odd to me, and might well sound odd to many fluejht speakers. In addition "* already bought before*" is redundant and would not be likely said or written by a fluent speaker.  I would favor "previously bought" or "already bought" or perhaps "previously purchased".

So I might use:

> - (3A) I had already bought everything you bought.
> - (3B) I had already bought all the same things that you bought.
> - (3C) All the things that you bought, I had already purchased.

Sentence (3C) uses fronting, and I don't find this unnatural in this context. Sentence such as (3A) or (3B) are perhaps more common, sand in this case fronting adds little, although it does place more emphasis on the things and less on "I". In composing (3C) I used "purchased" rather than repeating "bought" only to avoid a repetition that might sound awkward.